# Load Controller based on state params using Angular ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controllers, angular-ui-router

I am trying to load a controller based on a stateparam to make it reusable

```
.state("dashboard.item.detail", {
    url: "/detailId/:detailId/detailName/:detailName",
    views: {
       'main@': {
            templateUrl: function ($stateParams){
                //move this to a util function later
                var tempName = unescape($stateParams.detailName);
                tempName = tempName.replace(/\s/g, "-");
                return '../partials/slides/' + tempName + '.html';
            },
            resolve: {
                DetailData: ['DetailService', function(DetailService){
                    return DetailService.getDetails();
                }]
            },
            controller: function ($stateParams) {
                console.log( $stateParams.detailName + 'Ctrl');
                return $stateParams.detailName + 'Ctrl';
            }
        }
      }
})
```

Controller

```
    .controller('NemtCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'DetailData', function ($scope, $rootScope, detailData) {
    console.log(detailData);
}]);
```

The controller will work if I remove the function and just use (console will log detailData)

```
controller: 'NemtCtrl'
```

But won't work if I do:

```
controller: function ($stateParams) {
    return 'NemtCtrl';
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What is happening here is that when you write this:

```
controller: 'NemtCtrl'
```

You tell angular to get the controller named 'NemtCtrl'. But when you on the other hand write this:

```
controller: 
   function ($stateParams) {
        return 'NemtCtrl';
   }
```

you  are defining a controller for that state.

**Update**

According to the ui-router docs the way to do is as follows:

```
$stateProvider.state('contacts', {
  template: ...,
  controllerProvider: function($stateParams) {
      var ctrlName = $stateParams.type + "Controller";
      return ctrlName;
  }
})
```

You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)

**Update 2**

For your case it would be something like:

```
.state("dashboard.item.detail", {
  url: "/detailId/:detailId/detailName/:detailName",
  views: {

    'main@': {
      templateUrl:
        function ($stateParams){
          //move this to a util function later
          var tempName = unescape($stateParams.detailName);
          tempName = tempName.replace(/\s/g, "-");

          return '../partials/slides/' + tempName + '.html';
        },
      resolve: {
        DetailData: ['DetailService',
          function(DetailService){
            return DetailService.getDetails();
          }]
      },
      controllerProvider: //Change to controllerProvider instead of controller
        function ($stateParams) {
          //console.log( $stateParams.detailName + 'Ctrl');
          return $stateParams.detailName + 'Ctrl';
        }
    }

  }

})
```