# How to set dynamically a controller in HTML from JS with the controller name?

Tags: angularjs, controller

I have a view like follow :

```
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainController">[...]
<body ng-controller="currentController">[...]
```

I'd like to be able to set the body controller from a variable ($scope.currentController) of an upper controller (mainController). The controller `mainController` looks like follow :

```
angular.module("app").controller("mainController", function($scope) {
    $scope.currentController = "indexController"; // 'indexController' being the name of the controller I want to apply to the view
});
```

This doesn't work obviously, how can I set a controller dynamically from JS to the view ?

**EDIT :** (to @mrhobo answer)

I tried this, giving the fact that I have one file per controller :

```
angular.module("app").controller("mainController", function($scope, indexController) {
    $scope.currentController = indexController;
});
```

I got this error : [Doc Angular error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=indexControllerProvider%20%3C-%20indexController)

Comment: Is it acceptable to move the `mainController` to the `html` tag instead to achieve a parent-child relationship?

Comment: mainController is here to manage the controller used by the website. It can be `indexController` for the home page or `appController` for the application page. This two controllers do not manage the same things. I've tried to put them both on `mainController`, it works fine, but I have errors on my console because I have references to elements that doesn't exist in each one of them. That's why I'd prefer that `mainController` choose the one to apply depending on the page used. But in the code shown, I just show the basic idea of what I'd like to do : set a controller from JS using its name.

Comment: I think you are looking for the routing concept.

Comment: I already have an ng-view inside the body. (see the answer, I have replied to you) I know I could use ng-include/ng-if/ng-show/ng-hide/ng-switch,... but I'd like to avoid to have to copy the whole body twice...

Comment: It's solvable if it's acceptable to move the `mainController` to the `html` tag so that the controller on body is a child controller to `mainController`. Let me know if this is acceptable or not.

Comment: @tasseKATT Wops, my mistake, actually it is on the html tag already. ^^ (I edited the question)

Comment: You should probably cobsider using routing. One way to solve this problem is suggested here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26413076/load-controller-based-on-state-params-using-angular-ui-router/26413495#26413495

Comment: I assume the `currentController` can change during runtime?

Comment: @tasseKATT Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply point to the controller's constructor function.

```
$scope.currentController = indexController;
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2thj6zdk/

Comment: Looks like it is working ! =) But how can I get the constructor function of `Ctrl1` in `Main` controller if I have different files for each controller ? I get : https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=indexCtrlProvider%20%3C-%20indexCtrl

Comment: Just make sure the constructor is globally scoped like in the example.

Comment: How do I do that properly? I have one file per controller. (I edited my quastion)